# NodeJS: Functions proceeding before previous function returns

Tags: node.js

I'm getting started with NodeJS with a script (not a webapp), and this is baffling to me. I have the following simplified functions:

```
var request = require('request');

function first_func(name) {
  console.log('first_func(' + name + ')');
  var url = 'http://...' + name;
  var answers = new Array();  
  request(url, function(error, resp, html) {
    ...
    answers.push(x);
  });
  return answers;
}

function second_func(answers) {
  var results = new Array();
  for (var a in answers) {
    var url = 'http://...' + a;
    request(url, function(error, resp, html) {
      ...
      results.push(x);
    });
  }
  return results;
}
```

`first_func()` scraps a directory page, and `second_func()` scraps the particular page for that entry. The script runs like this at the end of the script:

```
var names = ['a', 'b', ...];

function main() {
  for (var n in names) {
    var ans = first_func(names[n]);
    console.log('answers: ' + ans);
    for (var a in ans) {
      second_func(ans[a]);
    }
  }
}

main();
```

For some reason NodeJS is doing `first_func()` and `second_func()` in parallel. Why isn't it waiting for `first_func()` to complete before running `second_func()`? The output is:

> answers: undefined
>
> first_func(a)
>
> first_func(b)
>
> ...

Why is NodeJS jumping into that inner `for` loop in `main()` before waiting for `first_func()` to return?

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of async programming!  `request` is an asynchronous method, so `first_func` and `second_func` return before the `request` callbacks are called.

Comment: This related question should help clarify what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [async module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) to work around this. It would look something like the following:

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

function first_func(name, done) {
  console.log('first_func(' + name + ')');
  var url = 'http://...' + name;
  request(url, function(error, resp, html) {
    ...
    done(answers);
  });
}

function second_func(answers, done) {
  var results = new Array();
  async.each(answers, function(answer, next) {
    var url = 'http://...' + a;
    request(url, function(error, resp, html) {
      ...
      results.push(x);
      next();
    });
  }, function(err) {
    done(results);
  });
}

var names = ['a', 'b', ...];

function main() {
  async.each(names, function(name, next) {
    first_func(name, function(err, answers) {
      second_func(answers, function(results) {
        // do something wit results
        next();
      });
    });
  }, function(err) {
    // done will everything
  });  
}

main();
```

You basically call a function when you're done getting the values you need instead of returning them. The async module will let you iterate over arrays in an async friendly way.